# Inserting a responsive image into a ASP.NET MVC5 project with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to scaffolding an application, and I would like my website to be responsive with mobiles.

I would like to insert a logo, but I really don't know how to do it like the image below:

[image]

I would like an image to be where the blue box is. What is the `HTML` tag to do this?

When inserting the image, I would like the image to resize and be proportionate to the rest of the page.

Here is the view that I have created so far:

```
@model someModel.Models.LoginViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="USUÁRIO"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="SENHA" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Entrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register", "Account")'">Ainda Não Tenho Conta</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Esqueci Meu Usuário Ou Senha</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: _“I want put a responsive logo, but I really don't know why”_ – well if you don’t know _why_ you want to do what you want to do … then how are _we_ supposed to know …?

Comment: My bad, english isn't my native language. I mean I don't know how

Comment: Could you clarify if you don't know how to make an image responsive or don't know how to actually put the image there? A snapshot of your html would also help please.

Comment: I don't know how to put an image in the blue box. I tried explain better and put my cshtml file. Please, take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a few things here. The first thing is inserting an image. This can be achieved with the `img` tag that is part of HTML. This is for actually inserting the image and nothing more.

The second part is the classes that bootstrap includes. I won't talk about `col-md-12` as you're already using that. The `text-center` (which is built-in to bootstrap) class will center the image like your request into the middle of the `div`.

The third part which isn't required here is the `@Url.Content("path to image")` which is razor syntax. Essentially, this generates the physical address of the image location when rendered. As an example, I would create a folder called `Images` in my project which would sit here `C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Images\image.png` and therefore render as `Images\image.png`. As per the comment, a more realistic version would be `@Url.Content("~/Images/image.png")`. The reason for using this is because no matter where the page is located within the hierarchy of the project, the razor syntax will make sure it points to the right location.

The forth part is the `alt="image"` attribute which is there to make it compliant with W3 standards. At a basic level, it means if the image is not available, the alternative that will be given instead of the image is some text which will display `image`.

Finally is the class of the image which is `img-responsive`. This is a built-in bootstrap class which makes the image responsive to resizing of the browser / different viewport sizes.

Putting all this together, we end up with a code block that should be located above your first input like:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <img src="@url.content("path to image")" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Here's all of the references towards the answer:

- [`img` html tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)
- [Twitter Bootstrap Alignment Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)
- [@Url.Content helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492566(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [`alt` img attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp)
- [`img-responsive` Twitter Bootstrap Class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

Comment: The class img-responsive is from bootstrap right? Can you point me the documentation url for me read more about?

Comment: The class is inherited from bootstraps css. Regarding @url.content this is part of the razor syntax. I'll grab the reference later for you when I'm not on my phone but as an example, @url.content("~/Images/image.png")